# Where can I find country and city tables

Tags: geocoding, country-codes

Is there anywhere I can obtain SQL that will create a country table and city table loaded with entries. It would be great if the cities linked to their country and also if the cities had coordinates. The data would be used to populate select options and also plot markers onto a GoogleMap.

Comment: US centric or trying to handle the whole world? How precise do you need it to be? [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Geographical_coordinates) seems like a starting point to me

Comment: whole world! cheers i'll check the link

Comment: To be honest the table is a little too comprehensive! I search for name LIKE 'Edinburgh' and got every hotel and hospital in Edinburgh as well as Edinburgh. I'm just worried that for an ajax dropdown chain this is going to take a bit too long to query. I'm also not sure what fcode means what. A city can appear more than once but different fcodes

Answer (score 0):

I have used the txt formated database from geonames.org.

Heres a description on [how to download](http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/732.page) the txt files and here's a description on how to [import into MySql](http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/80.page).

I got it into my mysql databse with no real problem, just remember to add indexes to your tables as some of them will be huge!

Comment: Does this include cities? I had a look and it looks like it's only countries

Comment: Yes, cities are included - take another look at the file named allcountries from the download link im my answer. It contains all cities with long/lat, it even holds population and elevation for each city!

Comment: uh oh the file is ~900MB too big to open in word or Notepadd++ will need to find a way to open it now

Comment: As I remember they also had a downloadable MS Access database. OR you can follow the link in my answer with description to import into mySql database.

Comment: Ok so I got the table installed (geoname) but it seems that the cities and countries are mixed. How do I which is a country and which is a City?

Comment: I belive countries are not represented in geoname table. It does however contain states and a lot of different location types. Check the table feature_codes which holds a description on what type of entry you have in geoname. For a list of only countries check the country_info table.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering an old question, but I landed here looking for the same information and it doesn't seem to be answered clearly anywhere, so here goes.

The 'allCountries' data from geonames is extremely extensive (to put it lightly) and is overkill for most applications. The 'cities1000' makes a lot more sense and has a far more manageable size. Importing it into MySQL is quite simple as long as you have SSH access to the server.

1. Download the file
   `wget http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities1000.zip`
2. Extract it `unzip cities1000.zip`
3. Run the following query (don't forget to replace MyDatabase with your database's name and the table's name must match the file's name)

.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyDatabase`.`cities1000` (
  `geo_id`               INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `geo_name`             VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `geo_ansiname`         VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `geo_alternate_names`  VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `geo_latitude`         DOUBLE PRECISION(11,7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_longitude`        DOUBLE PRECISION(11,7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_feature_class`    CHAR(1) ,
  `geo_feature_code`     VARCHAR(10) ,
  `geo_country_code`     CHAR(2),
  `geo_country_code2`    VARCHAR(60),
  `geo_admin1_code`      VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
  `geo_admin2_code`      VARCHAR(80) DEFAULT '',
  `geo_admin3_code`      VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
  `geo_admin4_code`      VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
  `geo_population`       BIGINT(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_elevation`        INT(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_gtopo30`          INT(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_timezone`         VARCHAR(40),
  `geo_mod_date`         DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00'

) CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```

4. Import the downloaded file into the database (you will need to change the command to match your server's configuration)

`mysqlimport -h localhost -u MySQL-USER -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' --lines-terminated-by='\n' --local MyDatabase /path-to/cities1000.txt`

5. ***Very important:*** add indexes to relevant field(s)

That's it! A still extremely comprehensive list of cities worldwide without all the "junk" in the 'allCountries' file.

The main issue with the data is that if you want countries, you're going to have to build that table yourself and add foreign keys linking them to the cities, but a second [data source](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/country_codes) (available in XML) and a few clever queries will do the trick.